# Error en PHP: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php

Me sale este error me podrían ayudar

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\EPWeb\Admin\Control\ControlUsuario.php on line 14

Este es el codigo:

```
function IngresarUsuario($nombreusuario,$apellidousuario,$nacionalidadusuario,$cedulausuario, $pasaporteusuario,$correousuario,$profesionusuario,$telefonousuario)
{
    $mensaje = "";

    if(isset($nombreusuario,$apellidousuario,$nacionalidadusuario,$cedulausuario,$correousuario,$profesionusuario, $telefonousuario))
    {

        $tipoUsuario = "1";
        $FechaUsuario = getdate();

        $query = "INSERT INTO persona(nombrep, apellidop, nacionalidadp, cedulap, pasaportep, telefonop, correop, profesionp, fecha) VALUES ('".$nombreusuario."','".$apellidousuario."','".$nacionalidadusuario."','".$cedulausuario."','".$pasaporteusuario."','".$telefonousuario."','".$correousuario."','".$profesionusuario."','".$FechaUsuario."')";

    $con = conexionBD();
    $accion = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if($accion)
    {
        $mensaje= "Correcto";
    }else
    {
        $mensaje= "No se pudo ejecutar la acción";
    }



    }else
    {
        $mensaje = "Los datos no fueron recibidos correctamente";
    }


    return $mensaje;
}
```

Comment: `Array to string conversion` ocurre cuando **intentas usar un array como si fuera una cadena**. ¿Cuál es la línea 14 del archivo `ControlUsuario.php`? En esa línea, al menos una de las variables es un array y tú lo usas como si de una cadena se tratase.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

El método `getDate()` te devuelve un elemento de tipo `Array`. Puedes utilizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$currDate = getDate(); // generas un llamado al metodo`

$FechaUsuario = $currDate['year'] . "-" . $currDate['mon'] . "-" . $currDate['mday']; // y utilizas los valores regresados por el método
```

Puedes ver más información en la [documentación oficial de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.getdate.php).

Comment: Lo hice y ahora me sale un error en esa linea

Comment: A non-numeric value encountered ese error ahora me sale

Comment: En PHP las concatenaciones se realizan con `'.'` y no con `'+'`.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando la respuesta de @808HS y corrigiendo el operador de concatenación, la respuesta sería:

```
$currDate = getDate(); // generas un llamado al metodo

$FechaUsuario = $currDate['year'] . "-" . $currDate['mon'] . "-" . $currDate['mday'];
```